# How to generate secret key using dart and flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, token

How can i generate a secret key in flutter and dart. I have tried but kept getting the following error.
Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid length, must be multiple of four (at character 27)\

```
static secretKey(String ss) async {
    String base64Key = 'xyz';
    String message = ss;
   

    List<int> messageBytes = utf8.encode(message);
    List<int> key = base64.decode(base64Key);
    Hmac hmac = Hmac(sha256, key);
    Digest digest = hmac.convert(messageBytes);

    String base64Mac = base64.encode(digest.bytes);
    print(base64Mac);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing with the base64 key is that you need to be able to divide it in a factor of 4, but if your key is not coming out to be a multiple of 4 then you can do 2 things:

**1. Use normalise method:** (Recommended)

You can normalise a base64 key to:

- Unescape any %-escapes.
- Only allow valid characters (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, /    and +).
- Normalize a    _ or - character to / or +.
- Validate that    existing    padding (trailing = characters) is
  correct.
- If no padding    exists,    add    correct padding if    necessary
  and possible.
- Validate that       the    length is correct    (a    multiple of
  four).

  Done by:  `base64Key.normalize(base64ToNormalize)`

You can read more here : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/Base64Codec/normalize.html

**2. Perform manual modification:**
You can use a basic if else method to determine if the generated key is a multiple of 4 or not :

```
        if (base64Key.length % 4 > 0) { 
            base64Key += '=' * (4 - base64Key .length % 4)
        }
```